# Proof concerning basic solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Prove that every basic solution of $Ax=b$ (where $A$ is a matrix of rank $r$) is set by $r$ linearly independent columns of matrix $A$ (so it is $[A^{k_1}\dots A^{k_r}]\bar{x}=b$ where $A^{k_1},\dots A^{k_r}$ are some linearly independend columns of matrix $A$, and we derive basic solution $x$ from $\bar{x}$ by inserting zeros on positions different from $k_1,\dots k_r$).

I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help?

Comment: So, you've defined $A$ and how to construct it, and your question is "Prove that every basic solution of $Ax = b$,..."?  What are we proving about these basic solutions?

Comment: Also, if you have any thoughts on how the problem should be approached or if you've tried anything so far, you should add that information to your question.

Comment: "Prove that every basic solution of $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a matrix of rank $r$ is set by $r$ linearly independent columns of matrix $A$".

Answer (score 1):

Having $\bar{x}$, you can define $x$ as

$$
x_i = \left\{\begin{array}{l}\bar{x}_{k_j} \quad \textrm{if} \quad i=k_j\\0 \quad \textrm{otherwise}\end{array}\right.\textrm{.}
$$

Comment: and that's all?

Comment: Yes, just check whether it works or not.